# How to display Image for background on stacklayout in iOS project using xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to display a photo as a background on stacklayout.

1. I create a folder in the iOS project under Resources (The strange thing is that the folder is not visible in Solution Explorer but is seen through Finder /on my Mac/)
2. I put a name for the folder `Images` and inside I put a picture with the name `Scattering.jpg`
3. Inside into my stacklayout I put this code:

   ```
    <StackLayout>
    <Image Source="Images/Scattering.jpg" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" > </Image></StackLayout>
   ```

But the image does not appear.

I will attach a screenshot from my solution explorer and the finder on my mac.

[image: In the solution explorer folder Images is not visible]

[image: In the Finder these folder Images are visible]

Comment: Right click on the solution Display Options -> Show show All Files. Then check iOS Resource folder. Images folder will be shown. Include Image folder (Include in project) and then check application shows that image. You can use [Image asset also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=macos)

Comment: Now I see the folder under Rerources folder but this method is very easy and why not worked for me

Comment: Did you include Images folder into your project (Right click on the Images folder and click include in project). If you have done. Then check what is build action for that image. Right click on the image. click on build action then select Bundle Resource. Then it should work. For testing hardcode image withrequest and heightrequest in XAML.

Comment: I have summarised my comments as answer. If is helps to fix your issue. Please mark this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the Solution -> Display Options -> Show All Files

Browse to iOS Resource folder and include Images folder (Right click, Include In Project)

Then, Right click on the image and make sure "Build Action" is BundleResource.

Set WithRequest and HeightRequest for the image to verify it's appearing.